# Outputing the first charachter of a UTF-8 array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, utf-8

I'm trying to pick out a single character from a Hebrew array in PHP.

The str_split function doesn't seem to work, and characters within the array are displayed as a black diamond with a question mark inside.

If I echo a single letter, the screen output displays "Array".

I also tried treating the string as an array and doing something like this: echo $string[0];. However that didn't give me different results.

How can I pick out the first letter of a word while working with a UTF-8 encoded format?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: _displayed as a black diamond with a question mark inside_ this means wherever you are trying to print it, doesn't have the proper encoding and the font to display the characters.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

```
$firstChar = mb_substr($str, 0, 1);
```

> If I echo a single letter, the screen output displays "Array".

It would do that only if you were trying to print an array.

Comment: @Shmuli *didn't work* won't help anyone. What didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: @alex , missed / not applied `$encoding` argument, maybe? `mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @CORRUPT The OP should use [`mb_internal_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php).

Comment: @alex, the OP's question is about array of strings , not strings

Comment: @Amir The OP can surely wrap the code in a loop of subscript their preferred member. :)

Answer (score 1):

If `$array` is your array of unicode strings.

```
 mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
 foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
$firstchar[$key]=mb_substr($value, 0, 1);
}
var_export($firstchar);
```